# CSS: How do i stop a fixed navbar from overlapping scrollbar?

Tags: css, css-position

I am creating a simple layout. As soon as i click search the navbar overlaps sidebar scrollbar. How can i fix this ?.

Here is the code

```js
 $('document').ready(function () {


            $('.search-icon').click(function () {

                var search_form = $('.search-form');

                if(search_form.hasClass("form-open"))
                {
                    // form is open, close the form
                    $('.search-form').toggle();
                    $('.search-form').removeClass("form-open");

                }

                else
                {
                    // open the form
                    $('.search-form').toggle();
                    $('.search-form').addClass("form-open");

                }

            });

        });
```

```css
        
        ul{
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        div.section-inner{
            max-width: 1100px;
            padding: 0 15px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .nav{
            background-color: #222;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .nav .site-title{
            font-size: 1.5em;
            display: inline-block;
            font-weight: bold;
            float: left;
            color: #fff;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 10px 10px;
        }

        .nav  a{
            color: #fff;
        }

        .nav ul a{
            font-size: 1.5em;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 10px 10px;
        }

        .nav ul a:hover{
            background-color: #4a3f3f;
        }

        .nav ul{
            list-style-type: none;
            /*display: inline-block;*/
            float: right;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .nav ul li{
            float: left;
        }

         .clearfix:after{
            content: '';
            display: block;
            clear: both;
        }

         .clear{
            clear: both;
         }

        .nav .search-icon{
            background: url("https://media-mediatemple.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/smashing-magazine/assets/images/search-icon.svg") 50% 50% no-repeat #222;
            font-size: 12px;
            padding: 18px 20px;
            /* background-color: #d67474; */
            display: inline-block;
            background-size: 2.5em;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-top: 2.5px;
            float: right;
        }

        .search-form{
            clear: both;
            display: none;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px 0;
        }

        .search-form input {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 6px 24px;
            font-size: 16px;
            outline: none;
            border: 1px solid;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }

        .search-form input[type="text"]{
            width: 20em;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }


        .search-form button {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .main-body .sidebar{
            position: fixed;
            width: 250px;
            height: 500px;
            overflow: scroll;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            /*z-index: -1;*/
        }

        .main-body .sidebar .course-title{
            margin-top: 0;
            font-size: 2.2em;
        }

        .main-body .sidebar ul{
            padding-left: 20px;

        }

        .main-body .sidebar .lesson{
            font-size: 1.5em;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .main-body .sidebar li{
            font-size: 1.2em;
            line-height: 1.6;
        }

        .main-body .main{
            /*margin-top: 20px;*/
            margin-top: 55px;
            margin-left: 290px;
        }

        .main-body .main h2{
            margin-top: 0;
            font-size: 21px;
        }

        .main-body .main .code-snippet{
            font-size: 1.8em;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--nav-->
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="section-inner clearfix">
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="">EXAMPLE.COM</a></h1>

            <div class="mnb">

                <div class="navicon">
                </div>

                <div class="search-icon">
                    <a href="#"></a>
                </div>

            </div>

            <ul class="nav-list">
                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="search-form clear">
                <form action="#">
                    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..." />
                    <input type="submit" value="Search">
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/nav-->

    <!--main-body-->
    <div class="main-body">
        <div class="section-inner clearfix">
            <!--sidebar-->
            <div class="sidebar">
              <h3>Title</h3>
              <h3 class="lesson">Chapter 1</h3>
              <ul>
                  <li>Item 1</li>
                  <li>Item 2</li>
                  <li>Item 3</li>
                  <li>Item 4</li>
                  <li>Item 5</li>
                  <li>Item 1</li>
                  <li>Item 2</li>
                  <li>Item 3</li>
                  <li>Item 4</li>
                  <li>Item 5</li>
                  <li>Item 1</li>
                  <li>Item 2</li>
                  <li>Item 3</li>
                  <li>Item 4</li>
                  <li>Item 5</li>
                  <li>Item 1</li>
                  <li>Item 2</li>
                  <li>Item 3</li>
                  <li>Item 4</li>
                  <li>Item 5</li>
                  <li>Item 1</li>
                  <li>Item 2</li>
                  <li>Item 3</li>
                  <li>Item 4</li>
                  <li>Item 5</li>
              </ul>                                    
            </div>
            <!--/sidebar-->

            <div class="main">
                <h2>Headling 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus aliquam at atque consectetur corporis, culpa eaque esse explicabo fugit hic laboriosam laborum necessitatibus nesciunt obcaecati quaerat rem rerum saepe vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, culpa hic illum numquam sapiente tenetur? Atque harum maiores soluta voluptate! Accusantium, consequatur doloremque fugit laudantium optio pariatur placeat repellat sequi.</p>

                <h2>Headling 2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus aliquam at atque consectetur corporis, culpa eaque esse explicabo fugit hic laboriosam laborum necessitatibus nesciunt obcaecati quaerat rem rerum saepe vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, culpa hic illum numquam sapiente tenetur? Atque harum maiores soluta voluptate! Accusantium, consequatur doloremque fugit laudantium optio pariatur placeat repellat sequi.</p>

                <h2>Headling 3</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus aliquam at atque consectetur corporis, culpa eaque esse explicabo fugit hic laboriosam laborum necessitatibus nesciunt obcaecati quaerat rem rerum saepe vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, culpa hic illum numquam sapiente tenetur? Atque harum maiores soluta voluptate! Accusantium, consequatur doloremque fugit laudantium optio pariatur placeat repellat sequi.</p>

                <h2>Headling 4</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus aliquam at atque consectetur corporis, culpa eaque esse explicabo fugit hic laboriosam laborum necessitatibus nesciunt obcaecati quaerat rem rerum saepe vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, culpa hic illum numquam sapiente tenetur? Atque harum maiores soluta voluptate! Accusantium, consequatur doloremque fugit laudantium optio pariatur placeat repellat sequi.</p>

                 <h2>Headling 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus aliquam at atque consectetur corporis, culpa eaque esse explicabo fugit hic laboriosam laborum necessitatibus nesciunt obcaecati quaerat rem rerum saepe vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, culpa hic illum numquam sapiente tenetur? Atque harum maiores soluta voluptate! Accusantium, consequatur doloremque fugit laudantium optio pariatur placeat repellat sequi.</p>

                <h2>Headling 2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus aliquam at atque consectetur corporis, culpa eaque esse explicabo fugit hic laboriosam laborum necessitatibus nesciunt obcaecati quaerat rem rerum saepe vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, culpa hic illum numquam sapiente tenetur? Atque harum maiores soluta voluptate! Accusantium, consequatur doloremque fugit laudantium optio pariatur placeat repellat sequi.</p>

                <h2>Headling 3</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus aliquam at atque consectetur corporis, culpa eaque esse explicabo fugit hic laboriosam laborum necessitatibus nesciunt obcaecati quaerat rem rerum saepe vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, culpa hic illum numquam sapiente tenetur? Atque harum maiores soluta voluptate! Accusantium, consequatur doloremque fugit laudantium optio pariatur placeat repellat sequi.</p>


            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <!--/main-body-->
```

I already tried setting `z-index` to `-1` in but it didn't work. How do i fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `z-index: 1` to `.nav`

```
.nav {
    background-color: #222;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is simple z-index problem.**

Just give your .nav class z-index greater than that of the sidebar. Here is the css you need to add and everything will work good.

```
.nav{z-index:1;}
```